# How to get Top Seller Products order by qty_ordered DESC in Magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1, php-7.2, best-seller

I'm trying to show the Top 4 Selling Product(s) with order by qty_ordered DESC in frontend like Admin Dashboard best seller's short view. But it will not displayed data in the exact way like Admin Dashboard. My code is given below:

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\Html\Pager;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory as BestSellersCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions;

/**
 * Catalog Products List widget block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList //implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{

/**
 * Instance of pager block
 *
 * @var Pager
 */
protected $pager;

/**
 * @var Context
 */
protected $httpContext;

/**
 * Catalog product visibility
 *
 * @var Visibility
 */
protected $catalogProductVisibility;

/**
 * Product collection factory
 *
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $productCollectionFactory;

protected $_bestSellersCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @var Builder
 */
protected $sqlBuilder;

/**
 * @var Rule
 */
protected $rule;

/**
 * @var Conditions
 */
protected $conditionsHelper;

/**
 * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
 */
private $priceCurrency;

/**
 * Json Serializer Instance
 *
 * @var Json
 */
private $json;

/**
 * @var LayoutFactory
 */
private $layoutFactory;

/**
 * @var EncoderInterface|null
 */
private $urlEncoder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList
 */
private $rendererListBlock;

/**
 * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
 */
private $categoryRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
 * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
 * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
 * @param Context $httpContext
 * @param Builder $sqlBuilder
 * @param Rule $rule
 * @param Conditions $conditionsHelper
 * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
 * @param array $data
 * @param Json|null $json
 * @param LayoutFactory|null $layoutFactory
 * @param EncoderInterface|null $urlEncoder
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    Context $httpContext,
    Builder $sqlBuilder,
    Rule $rule,
    Conditions $conditionsHelper,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    BestSellersCollectionFactory $bestSellersCollectionFactory,
    array $data = [],
    Json $json = null,
    LayoutFactory $layoutFactory = null,
    EncoderInterface $urlEncoder = null
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    $this->sqlBuilder = $sqlBuilder;
    $this->rule = $rule;
    $this->conditionsHelper = $conditionsHelper;
    $this->json = $json ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LayoutFactory::class);
    $this->urlEncoder = $urlEncoder ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(EncoderInterface::class);
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;

    $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory = $bestSellersCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $productCollectionFactory,
        $catalogProductVisibility,
        $httpContext,
        $sqlBuilder,
        $rule,
        $conditionsHelper,
        $categoryRepository,
        $data
    );
}


public function getBestsellerProductCollection()
{
    
    //$productIds  = [];
    $bestSellers = $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory->create()
        ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
        //->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
        //->setPeriod('month');   
        ->setPeriod('year');

    $bestSellers->setPageSize(4);

    $bestSellers->addStoreFilter(1)->getSelect()->order('qty_ordered DESC');
    

    //echo $bestSellers->getSelect()->__toString();

    foreach ($bestSellers as $product) {
        $prodIds[] = $product->getProductId();
    }

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($prodIds); exit();

    //$productIds = array_slice(array_unique($prodIds), 0, 4);
    // //echo "<pre>"; print_r(array_unique($productIds)); exit();
    // echo "<pre>"; print_r($productIds); exit();

    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->addIdFilter($productIds);
    $collection->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
        ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
        //->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount());

    return $collection;
}

}
```

I cann't understand where I'm wrong to show the Top 4 Seller Products in frontend. If any one knows where there is issue, please give a proper solution(s) or clue(s).

Answer (score 0):

try to use this to get best seller product by month and then manipulate this to get top 4:

Create one block file on your custom extension

> app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Test.php

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
 
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory as BestSellersCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
 
class Test extends Template
{
    protected $_bestSellersCollectionFactory;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        BestSellersCollectionFactory $bestSellersCollectionFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory = $bestSellersCollectionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory;
     parent::__construct($context);
    }
   
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $productIds = [];
        $bestSellers = $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory->create()
            ->setPeriod('month');
        foreach ($bestSellers as $product) {
            $productIds[] = $product->getProductId();
        }
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addIdFilter($productIds);
        $collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
            ->setPageSize(count($productIds));
        return $collection;
    }
 
    public function getStoreId(){
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }
}
```

use this block function **getProductCollection** to get best seller collection.

Comment: Hi Nihal, Thank you for your reply. Yes, it is also coming fine by the provided code, but not like Admin Dashboard best seller's small short view, means for example, A product qty 100 soled out, B product qty 65 soled out, C product qty 95, D product qty 110, E qty 105, then it should be shown Product D, E, A, C, B. It shows a haphazardly, not according to the requirement if it has been printed out echo "<pre>"; print_r($productIds); exit(); before $collection = ... . Please check it thoroughly.

Comment: you can show the collection in desc on wty basis by using custom sorting on collection array.

Comment: I think you are talking about \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar. No, I need this feature in Home page to construct the simple list like admin dashboard best seller's small short view.

Comment: as you have said above you want the result collection to be sorted desc, what iam saying is you can use php sort array function like this

$price = array();
foreach ($inventory as $key => $row)
{
    $price[$key] = $row['price'];
}
array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $inventory);
after you get the collection